# System.IO.PathTooLongException while installing Sitecore

Tags: sim

Encountered with below exception while installing Sitecore using SIM. Any ideas how to deal with this?

```
   10 14:46:16,213 INFO  Unzipping the 'D:\SIMSupport\Sitecores\Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160302.zip' archive to the 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\sc81rev160302\550030d3-34f6-4996-b650-c78c96f9e97a' folder
  10 14:47:27,145 ERROR Processor of type 'SIM.Pipelines.Install.Extract' (a part of the 'install' pipeline) failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.InternalExtract(String baseDir, Stream outstream, String password)
   at SIM.Base.ZipProvider.UnpackZip(String packagePath, String path, Action`1 incrementProgress, String ignore)
   at SIM.Pipelines.Install.Extract.Process(InstallArgs args)
   at SIM.Pipelines.Install.InstallProcessor.Process(ProcessorArgs args)
   at SIM.Pipelines.Processors.Processor.Execute(ProcessorArgs args)
  10 14:47:27,170 INFO  Appending host: sc81rev160302
   1 14:47:30,091 ERROR Extracting files action failed with message: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Comment: Why do you have a GUID as part of your installation path?  Remove it, and you'll be under the windows path length limitation

Comment: @MarkCassidy-  Thanks for pointing that, but the GUID is being added by SIM itself while extracting Sitecore Zip file. it does not happen when I manually extract it.

Comment: Update to latest version of SIM then. I just tried installing your exact version of Sitecore to `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc812` and encountered no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the path length limit so that your paths can be longer than 260 characters.

In regedit, go to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem and set LongPathsEnabled to 1.

Comment: That will only help if SIM is compiled with .NET 4.6.2 or higher though